# Jmeter Dashboard empty on Jenkins HTML report publish

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

I'm successfully generating a jmeter dashboard through maven jmeter plug in. I have this build configured on Jenkins to run and it also generates the dashboard successfully with all graphs/data showing. I now try to publish this dashboard with the HTML publisher so it can be accessed from the Jenkins build. The plugin works correctly and moves the generated dashboard with all necessary folders/files to the archive location and displays a link on the build page to the index.html.

If I click that link however it opens the index page but everything is empty...just showing the headings/navigation e.g.:
[Empty dashboard through jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZAxW.jpg)
. 
If I open the exact same dashboard index page through the build server machine it displays fine and everything shows up and works.

I've added the following to jenkins.xml in hopes it is a css etc. permission issue:

-Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=

But that did not do anything.

Any ideas why the jmeter dashboard report might not be displaying correctly through Jenkins but does when access directly through the server? As a side note, I'm also publishing jacoco and surefire reports the exact same way and they display fine. I'm also using the performance plug in and that also pulls the data and shows some graphs from jmeter as well...but I'd like the nice dashboard to work, too.

Thanks!

Comment: I've figured it out...somewhat super trivial and odd...for some reason launching the dashboard page through our jenkins instance renders the page in IE7 mode instead of edge/11 which breaks the page and shows nothing. Switching to edge/11 shows all the content as expected. So now just need to figure out why when displaying that page it defaults to that.


--edit: unchecking "Display intranet sites in Compatibly" makes it work.

Comment: Can you tell me where did you uncheck that value "Display intranet sites in Compatibly" ?

Answer (score 6):

To solve this, go to Manage Jenkins, Script Console section and type this command:

> System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "")

Press Run. After that run your build again and now you should be able to see generated dashboard...

Comment: I've tried that approach as well as mentioned in my post to clear this property at the jenkins configuration level and that did not fix the problem.

Comment: Could you try this while Jenkins is up and running? I had same issue and I solved it with this approach...

Comment: Just tried again...same result...report shows up empty though it has all the content needed.

Comment: Even downloading the zip file of the dashboard that the publisher link gives me up top has all content and when opened shows it fine...it's just within Jenkins it doesn't want to.

Comment: I've figured it out...somewhat super trivial and odd...for some reason launching the dashboard page through our jenkins instance renders the page in IE7 mode instead of edge/11 which breaks the page and shows nothing. Switching to edge/11 shows all the content as expected. So now just need to figure out why when displaying that page it defaults to that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, that the dasboard of the jMeter-report was empty while accessing the dasboard unsing Firefox. While using Internet-Explorer and Chrome, the report was visible.

The solution and problem was, that we accessed the html-report using the ip adress of the jenkins-server and not the fqdn. After using the fqdn the report was accessible with Firefox as well.

Answer (score 0):

For autostart create a Groovy script file **$JENKINS_HOME/init.groovy**, or any **.groovy** file in the directory **$JENKINS_HOME/init.groovy.d/** with the following content:

```
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "sandbox allow-scripts; default-src 'self'; img-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline';")
```

systemctl restart jenkins

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Post-initialization+script

Answer (score 0):

I had a different issue. I was only able to see the report results when I downloaded the entire zip directory file from the Jenkins artifact page and unzip on my windows workstation. The report showed all of the data.